# Hide commandbutton when coverting Word Doc to PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

When converting to pdf using a commandbutton that creates an Outlook email, coverts docfile to pdf, and attached file - the pdf file still displays the commandbuttons on the form.

Is there a way to hide the commandbuttons or make them invisible before converting from Word Doc to pdf format.

```
If VName.Value = "" Then
     Doc.SaveAs ("Quotation_Blank 2016")    Else
     FileName = "QFORM" & "_" & JNumber.Value & "_" & VName.Value
     Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=THE_PATH & FileName, _
     ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF  
End If
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you just set the `.Visible` or `.Enabled` properties to False before you do the SaveAs - and then set them back to True before exiting? These are your command buttons (as opposed to system ones) correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the button type there might be a `Print Object` property for the button object that might show/hide the button when being exported.  Otherwise you might have to set the `Visible` property on the button to 'False' before exporting, then turn `Visible` back to 'True' after.  Might depend on if you're using 'ActiveX' controls or 'Form' controls, so you might have to play around with those settings a bit depending on your setup.

Comment: you are correct. I was able to set the button to invisible with activedocument.shapes(1).visible = False. Then set it back to .visible = True at the end of my code. I previously tried the object .Enabled, but was unsuccessful. Thank you for clarifying that for me.